# Changing image cyclically with animation WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, animation

I have an image control in my WPF application .Source is set by binding from a list named Items which is having 5 image sources

```
<Image x:Name="image1" Source="{Binding Items[0]}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

I need to load Items[1] to source after 1 minute with animation and need to load Items[2] after 1 more minute and continue like that. after the completion of 5 items I need the first item to be loaded again(cyclic). I need to do the changing with animation.How to implement that?

Comment: Try to use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282137/wpf-animate-image-source-change

Comment: @bakala12 I need the same.. But I couldn't see any binding in it